# Using cases to manage and track internal SF tasks?

Tags: administration, user-admin, bestpractice

We have multiple administrators and or power users performing various designated tasks and want to use cases to manage, track, report and document.

Anyone have any suggestions or best practices to achieve case implementation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using cases to track two internal SF items.

Projects

and Change Management.

For Projects we track who asked for the request, who does it benefit, and estimate of how much "work" it would be (relative value unit 0-10). My next step is going to be a project priority based on business value so we can have a single project list. I'm also going to be putting in place a scheduled release schedule so we prioritize only work that can fit within a pre-defined period of time for release.

For change management everytime we change a field, role, or object we create a case. we can then reference that case in the description (if available). When we make another change to that field or object we create a related case, and update the description. This way I can go backwards from the last change to the creation and the project that spawned it.

It's also good for expanding out what fields mean. IE, we created this field for this purpose, used by this group, and meaning XYZ.

I recommend you start small and slowly build up. What's most important for you to track? How do you want to "divvy" out the work? Who decides what's going to be done (or not)? Keep things small and simple so it's quick and easy to use. The last thing you want to occur is to spend 10 minutes documenting a task that takes 30 seconds.

Pretend you're creating a case process for customer service. How will you do it? You're essentially doing the same thing - it's just internal customers.

Comment: How did you determine the contacts to be assigned internally. Did you have to create a corporate account and then assign all internal users accounts? Seems the obvious conclusion.    I'm sure you had to add picklist values to 'type' and 'case reason' etc. (thanks Wizard, good stuff)

Comment: We already had a corporate account with contacts as internal users. We had an appexchange app that "sync to contact" our user records... plus we created as needed for non-sfdc users.
The contact was the person who made the request.
We used Type to flag if it was an Object, Field, Role, Profile, Report Request etc.. Case Reason was the Division - Team requesting (Eg Corporate - Marketing)

Comment: Might that be the appexchange app freebie, 
User Contact Sync Optimizer?  This seems like it would be a tremendous help! Thanks again for all the feedback.

Comment: I believe it's "User Contact Sync" by Sales Optimizer.

Comment: and I should correct myself. Case Reason we used to flag between a Change Management case and a Project Request case (we're using 1 record type for both). Case Origin we use to track division - Team

We also added a rich text field for "Details" and leave the description for Email to Case support.

Answer (score 2):

This is something we did for a while.  Some obvious things to take into consideration:
-Create a record type for your support tickets
-Ensure you have a process in place that doesn't let tickets fall through the cracks
-Make sure you have a system set up that notifies users of the status of their bugs/requests

That being said, we ended up abandoning our solution.  There are many very good out of the box ticket tracking solutions.  We went with Jira, but we also looked at asana and others that would do just fine.  These systems are purpose built for this type of application and have just been smoother and taken less administration time than our Salesforce case-based system.

Comment: I actually started with Jira and abandoned it. It worked well for bug tracking, but it felt lacking with projects. Plus, we felt it was a little weird the group pushing Salesforce adoption wasn't actually using the product themselves. Great recommendation on the separate record type!

Answer (score 1):

Just a shameless plug here: but we do all our project management directly inside of SFDC on our own product called: [TaskRay](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000055lKwEAI), it uses custom objects to create collaborative boards representing projects/project tasks.

I've used Jira, and actually built a custom integration to it from SFDC, but it's a bit overkill if your not doing software development in an agile environment.